# How to resolve error: ERROR 1442 (HY000) Can't update table 'table name' in stored function/trigger?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have one mysql procedure which update record from one master database to other database/s:
below is my procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE order_update (vmasterdb varchar(200),vdbnamelist VARCHAR(8000),tbl_name varchar(200),form_id varchar(200))
BEGIN
    DECLARE dbnamelist VARCHAR(8000);
    DECLARE pos int;
    DECLARE dbname VARCHAR(100);

    SET dbnamelist=vdbnamelist;
 WHILE LENGTH(dbnamelist) > 0 DO

        SET pos  = INSTR(dbnamelist,',') ;
        SET dbname = (CASE WHEN pos>0 THEN SUBSTRING(dbnamelist, 1, pos-1) else SUBSTRING(dbnamelist, 1) END);

IF tbl_name='tabOrder Form' THEN
SET @myCommand := concat('
    UPDATE ',vmasterdb,'.`tabOrder Form` b
           JOIN ',dbname,'.`tabOrder Form` a
           ON a.name = b.name
    SET
a.docstatus = b.docstatus,
a.parent = b.parent,
a.parentfield = b.parentfield,
a.order_calculation = b.order_calculation,
a.custom_customer = b.custom_customer
WHERE a.name=?');
    PREPARE myStatement FROM @myCommand;
    SET @c1 =form_id;
    EXECUTE myStatement USING @c1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE myStatement;

 END IF;
        if pos=0 then
    SET dbnamelist =null;
    else
        SET dbnamelist = SUBSTRING(dbnamelist, pos+1, LENGTH(dbnamelist)-pos);
    SET pos=0;
        end if;
    END WHILE;
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call this procedure by using following function

```
call generic_update_ord ('9fdcb2f441fcdd2e','e6d1e768ce7674e8,d5d776576c6042b6','tabOrder Form','ORD-00012')
```

I'm getting error

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'tabOrder Form' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger

In my function call my **Master DB** is (9fdcb2f441fcdd2e) and **two other DB's** are (e6d1e768ce7674e8) and (d5d776576c6042b6), I'm expecting to update other DB's once My master DB is getting updated.

Comment: Do you try to use the stored procedure from a stored function or trigger?.

Comment: I'm just calling a function, like : call generic_update_ord('...')

Comment: But from within a stored function or trigger?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood,
I already added one trigger, and I forgot to remove that that's why I'm getting this error.